# Trim email address from header of PHP Mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send email to my clients. But I am not satisfied with the output of the

[image]

I want to remove `<michael@gmail.com>` at the end of my name but not sure how to do it.

My current script:

```
$mail->SetFrom("michael@gmail.com",'Michael Chu');
$mail->XMailer = 'Microsoft Mailer';
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Subject = "TEST Email";
$mail->Body = "<p>TEST Email<p>";
```

Comment: I believe some mail programs do this automatically, thus it's not the code.

Comment: Indeed, you can't, and it's nothing you can control from PHPMailer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant parts in the PHPMailer code is in the Pre Send routine, which assembles the mail (and which is obviously called internally always before send):

```
public function preSend() {
    ...
    try {
        $this->error_count = 0; // Reset errors
        $this->mailHeader = '';
    ...         
        // Create body before headers in case body makes changes to headers (e.g. altering transfer encoding)
        $this->MIMEHeader = '';
        $this->MIMEBody = $this->createBody();
        // createBody may have added some headers, so retain them
        $tempheaders = $this->MIMEHeader;
        $this->MIMEHeader = $this->createHeader();
        $this->MIMEHeader .= $tempheaders;
    ...         
    return true;
```

This will be called always. Now: when we look at the createHeader-function we see this:

```
public function createHeader()
{
    $result = '';
    ...
    $result .= $this->addrAppend('From', [[trim($this->From), $this->FromName]]);
    ...
    return $result;
}
```

So: Create Header always adds the From Address part, but it relies on addrAppend to format it (passing 'From' and an array containing one address-array [email, name])

```
public function addrAppend($type, $addr)
{
    $addresses = [];
    foreach ($addr as $address) {
        $addresses[] = $this->addrFormat($address);
    }
    return $type . ': ' . implode(', ', $addresses) . static::$LE;
}
```

The address-array is passed on:

```
public function addrFormat($addr)
{
    if (empty($addr[1])) { // No name provided
        return $this->secureHeader($addr[0]);
    }
    return $this->encodeHeader($this->secureHeader($addr[1]), 'phrase') .
         ' <' . 
         $this->secureHeader($addr[0])
         . '>';
}
```

and formatted with the email... Nothing you can do about it.

So with phpmailer you can't do it. But you can write your own [subclass](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/extending.phps).
Probably something along those lines

```
<?php

//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Use PHPMailer as a base class and extend it
 */
class myPHPMailer extends PHPMailer
{

public function addrFormat($addr)
{
    if (empty($addr[1])) { // No name provided
            return $this->secureHeader($addr[0]);
        }
    else {          
            return $this->secureHeader($addr[1]);
    }
}   
}
```